# Convert %m-%d to dayofyear format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime-format

I have a DataFrame which has dates as string in the form '%m-%d' and I want to convert it to dayofyear format, how do I do that?

Comment: Which year? Current year?

Comment: Can we have [MCVE]?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a df like this:

```
df = {'date': ['12-31','01-01','07-02', '12-04','06-05'],
      'col1': [5,10,20,30,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)

   col1   date
0     5  12-31
1    10  01-01
2    20  07-02
3    30  12-04
4    20  06-05
```

You can convert the column `date` to `dayofyear` format in this way(non leap year):

```
df["date"]= pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%m-%d").dt.dayofyear
```

Output:

```
   col1  date
0     5   365
1    10     1
2    20   183
3    30   338
4    20   156
```

Comment: in my opinion nice solution :)

Comment: @jezrael Thank you :)